# SEO is off topic?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that in post closing SEO has become an option as an off topic question.

SEO is an important part of the Magento system with a lot of built in features. I myself have asked questions on the topic of SEO and my posts were never closed.

I'm just curious as to why SEO has been added as "off topic"?

Comment: What do you mean? I can not see this option.

Comment: @Alex it looks like it was for a single question as a suggested closing reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see reasons in the "off topic" list that others have been used on the same question:

[image: example]

So it's not an official reason, just a single opinion on a single question.

Comment: Ah okay I feel silly now, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

I think SEO has two sides here.

1. Problems or questions arising from built in Magento SEO features or even extensions (although extensions might be considered off-topic too)
2. General SEO questions/problems about optimization, indexing, Google results/ranking etc..

IMO number one definitely belongs on the Magento SE, number 2 does not. I think questions in category number 2 have a better chance on a fast and good answer on other SE's.

Answer (score 2):

I think general SEO questions should be off topic, whereas questions pertaining to the use of magento or magento extensions in regards to SEO is ok.

Answer (score 1):

to cite a different answer on a similar question

> SEO questions should be asked on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo), tagged with seo.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281382/716029

Reason: the whole area of SEO is as big as Magento as a whole. With a difference, that there is only a very small overlap of SEO with Magento Developers.

Doing SEO in a professional manner requires access to a few hundred websites at the lowest, the right connections to other expert People in the Field (like we Magento people are good connected to other Magento people) and reading a lot of news and books and so on.

If you want the best possible SEO answer, you should go where the experts are. They will not be here in the Magento Stackexchange